# Instalacion TypeScript y Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy iniciando con la instalación de herramientas necesarias para usar angular, inicie instalando nodejs con nmp, no tuve ningún problema y estas son las versiones instaladas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego debía instalar typescript, pero no me reconoce el comando tsc y tampoco envía la verificacion de que ya esta bien instalada en la consola, ni me muestra la versión, aquí se muestra como inicia a instalar con el comando npm install -g typescript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero despues de este paso intento verificar la instalación con tsc -v y tampoco me lo reconoce
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me pasa igual instalando angular con el comando npm install -g @angular/cli
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me reconoce cuando intento verificar la instalacion con ng version
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso ocurre porque no tienes `ng` ni `tsc` agregado al `PATH`. Cómo alternativa rápida, puedes correr los comandos agregando el prefijo `npm run`, por ejemplo `npm run ng version`, o bien, `npm run tsc -v`. La segunda alternativa para ejecutar los programas directamente es seguir [esta guía](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46066042/8838721) para agregar los programas al `PATH`. Por otro lado, considera usar PowerShell y dejar a un lado el viejo CMD. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: hola prueba con el de angular cli `ng --version`

Comment: trata de ejecutar `C:\WINDOWS\system32>where tsc` y `C:\WINDOWS\system32>where ng`--->y si queres comentame el resultado saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, ya logré solucionar el problema!